# Firefox doesnt print all contents of page

Tags: firefox, iframe, printing

When viewing specific htmls that has several iFrames, firefox/IE8/safari doesnt print all content. The page consists of 3 iframes. One of the iframes seen blank in print (and also in print preview).
What is the cause for this and how can I fix it?
In IE7 this works fine.
actual content:
[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/5180/actualcontent.jpg](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/5180/actualcontent.jpg)

Content that is printed in firefox(or print preview):
[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/1385/firefoxprintpreview.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/1385/firefoxprintpreview.jpg)

Why is the left iframe missing from the print?
Thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick google reveals that firefox has an issue with printing high iframes. You can read more about it [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Problems_printing_web_pages).

Comment: The link provided suggests solution for cutoff images or cutoff text , and solution to shrink print preview or similar. the issue here is that the whole iframe content is gone.